# An unhandled exception occurred: The package "@esbuild/darwin-arm64" could not be found, and is needed by esbuild

Tags: angular, esbuild

I have recently just upgraded to Angular 17. Running my application runs fine. But when I build the package with ng build, I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: The package "@esbuild/darwin-arm64" could not be found, and is needed by esbuild.


If you are installing esbuild with npm, make sure that you don't specify the
"--no-optional" or "--omit=optional" flags. The "optionalDependencies" feature
of "package.json" is used by esbuild to install the correct binary executable
for your current platform.
See "/private/var/folders/r3/lyljtcfd2bq5plstq3kjg5240000gr/T/ng-PDGTJw/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

```
So, I naturally try to install @esbuild/darwin-arm64 and I get this error:

[00:03] info Rebuilding package-lock.json
[00:03] info Cleaning up node_modules - this might take a moment...
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for @esbuild/darwin-arm64@0.19.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  arm64
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   darwin
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

For context, I am using an M1 Pro, so it my architecture should be arm64 but it seems npm is reading it as x64.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: which node version do you use ?

Comment: I am on Node v20.11.0

Comment: Put @esbuild/darwin-arm64 with compatible version to package.json, remove node_modules and lock file then run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was successfully resolved by manually clearing the node_modules using the command `rm -rf node_modules`, and then run command `npm i`.